# MySQL join tables where all left records are in right

Tags: mysql

I need to get matching records from table A that are also in table B. But I can't figure out if I can do this in just one query.

Table A

```
id | order_id | title
----------------------------------
 1 | 1114     | Product 1
 2 | 1115     | Product 1
 3 | 1115     | Product 2
 4 | 1116     | Product 1
 5 | 1117     | Product 3
 6 | 1118     | Product 4
 7 | 1118     | Product 5
```

Table B

```
id | order_id | a_id | title
----------------------------------
 1 | 2221     |    1 | Product 1
 2 | 2222     |    2 | Product 1
 3 | 2222     |    3 | Product 2
 4 | 2223     |    7 | Product 5
```

Now I need all `order_id` values from table A where all products are also in table B. So this would result in:

```
1114
1115
```

1116 fails because there is no `b.a_id` value `4`
1117 fails because there is no `b.a_id` value `5`
1118 fails because not both `6` AND `7` are in `b.a_id`

I tried an `INNER JOIN`, but this would also return `1118`. I also tried a `LEFT JOIN` with `WHERE b.a_id IS NULL`, but that is the exact opposite. So I tried a `RIGHT JOIN`, but that also returns `1118`.

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/240bd1/5).

I hope I made clear what my goal is and I'm curious if this could be managed by one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not perfect, but it does return the correct results for your existing data through the SQL Fiddle. Maybe you can use this as a starting point?

```
SELECT a.order_id, count(distinct a.id) as aCount, count(distinct b.a_id) as bCount
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
GROUP BY a.order_id
HAVING aCount = bCount;
```

Comment: This gives me indeed the correct answer. I run in on my database with real data, table A ~800.000 records and B ~ 45.000 records. Query run in ~ 600ms.

Answer (score 1):

It is doable in a single query:

```
SELECT a.order_id, COUNT(a.id) as cntA, COUNT(b.id) AS cntB
FROM a
  LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
GROUP BY a.order_id
HAVING cntA = cntB;
```

Comment: Same answer as Dave Rix! But this does indeed the job!